# How to make a modified mob spawn randomly on the map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm doing a RPG in minecraft with some friends but we don't know how to make a modified mob spawn randomly on the map. We have a mob, and we have set it’s name, attributes, and other data. But we don’t know how to get it in a random location.

We are playing in Minecraft JE 1.16.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/summon` to summon the entity normally. But immediately after, run the following `/spreadplayers` command:

```
/spreadplayers <centerX> <centerZ> 0.0 <maxRange> false @e[name="THE_MOB_TO_ACT_UPON"]
```

Replace the following things:

- `centerX` and `centerZ`: The centre of your arena.
- `maxRange`: How far from the centre can your entity be? The area is a square radius.
- The target selector at the end: Replace with a target selector that will target the entity that you've already summoned.

Comment: what do i need to do to stop them teleporting together

Comment: @LPA3227 What exactly do you mean?

Comment: all the mobs with that name teleport to a random place when the command is activated

Comment: @LPA3227 Then find a different way to target the mob. Use scoreboard tags, for example.